# Add value from another table by comparing tables columns

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have 2 tables in postgres like:

table A:

| unique_coords | unique_id |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
| . | . |

table B like:

| coords | id |
| --- | --- |
| a |  |
| a |  |
| c |  |
| d |  |
| c |  |
| c |  |
| d |  |
| c |  |

I want to fill the id column in table B based on table A. So the result will be like this:

| coords | id |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 1 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
| c | 3 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
| c | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple [UPDATE join](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-update-join/) syntax

```
UPDATE tableB
SET id = unique_id
FROM tableA
WHERE tableA.unique_coords = tableB.coords;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6f820b75952c90ae7cdeadec419f45f6